# Exporting rasters in GCS in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a raster that covers an entire country with the base data having a 0.05° resolution. The country spans two UTM zones, so I am reluctant to reproject the file to a projected coordinate system. The issue with this is that exporting the raster in Google Earth Engine requires the user to set a scale, which defaults to 1000m per pixel. This doesn't really work for a raster with a resolution that depends on the latitude. Is there a work-around for this issue? Below is an excerpt script of my data (though the AOI in the larger script is much bigger):

```
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[101.17563162758336, 18.896757345850304],
          [101.15365897133336, 18.70955737155526],
          [101.39535819008336, 18.69394798887354],
          [101.39535819008336, 18.912347927872148]]]);

var chirps = ee.ImageCollection("UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/DAILY")
            .filterDate('1984-06-01','1984-06-30')
            .filterBounds(aoi)

var chirpsMean = chirps.mean().clip(aoi)

Map.addLayer(chirpsMean)

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: chirpsMean,
  description: 'LaosExample',
  //scale: 5000,
  region: aoi
})
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found a post in the GEE developer's group (can't find the link atm) which basically said to use the nominal scale of the coordinate system as the export scale. I did that, adjusting for the degree resolution of my imagery:

```
var chirpsProjection = chirpsMean.projection()
  var chirpsScale = chirpsProjection.nominalScale()
  Export.image.toAsset({
  image: chirpsAnomPc,
  description: 'OrigScaleNoRepro005',
  scale: (chirpsAnomPcScale.getInfo()*0.05),
  region: aoi,
  maxPixels: 10e10
});
```