# Google Earth Engine: Error on point value extraction

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract rainfall (CHIRPS) values for a set of locations but I got the following error:

> Image.reduceRegions: Unable to find a crs

This does not happens with other datasets (such as terraclimate)

The error arise when i start downloading the table from Tasks.

Here is the link to the code I have run https://code.earthengine.google.com/c27f2156e81824b0990dcfe0b0a6f455

The error should be here:

```
// do extraction 
var ft = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List([]));

//Function to extract values from image collection based on point file and export as a table 
var fill = function(img, ini) {
  var inift = ee.FeatureCollection(ini);
  var scale = ee.Image(MM.first()).projection().nominalScale().getInfo()
  var ft2 = img.reduceRegions(pts, ee.Reducer.first(),scale);
  var date = img.date().format("YYYYMM");
  var ft3 = ft2.map(function(f){return f.set("date", date)});
return inift.merge(ft3);
};

// Iterates over the ImageCollection
var profile = ee.FeatureCollection(MM.iterate(fill, ft));
```

Comment: May I ask what does the 'ini' mean in the function(img,ini),and why should I transfer this 'ini' into featurecollection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of your images inside the collection do not contain bands. Therefore, the error is thrown. Filter out images which do not contain a band using (assuming the first images correctly contains a band):

```
// Filter out empty images
MM = MM.filter(ee.Filter.listContains('system:band_names', MM.first().bandNames().get(0)))
```

Furthermore, I think you will need to get the scale using the following, based on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315613/exporting-rasters-in-gcs-in-google-earth-engine):

```
// get scale 
var scale = MM.first().projection().nominalScale().multiply(0.05); print(scale)
```

As your feature collection was not shared, I drew a simple feature collection: [Link script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7dab03d593d5a0bd9a415e82331a599d)